# Index xts using string and return only observations at that exact time

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have an xts time series in R and am using the very handy function to subset the time series based on a string, for example

```
time_series["17/06/2006 12:00:00"]
```

This will return the nearest observation to that date/time - which is very handy in many situations. However, in this particular situation I only want to return the elements of the time series which are at that exact time. Is there a way to do this in xts using a nice date/time string like this?

In a more general case (I don't have this problem immediately now, but suspect I may run into it soon) - is it possible to extract the closest observation within a certain period of time? For example, the closest observation to the given date/time, assuming it is within 10 minutes of the given date/time - otherwise just discard that observation.

I suspect this more general case may require me writing a function to do this - which I am happy to do - I just wanted to check whether the more specific case (or the general case) was already catered for in xts.

Comment: Does the sample code you provided work?  I think it should be `time_series["2006-06-17 12:00:00"]`

Comment: Your example will not work correctly because `"17/06/2006"` is not a valid ISO datetime representation.

Comment: time_series["2006-06-17 12:00:00"] will return all values that occur between 12:00:00.000000 and 12:00:00.999999.  That's not the same as "the nearest observation to that date/time"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the only way to do this is to use a subset that begins at the time you're interested in, then get the first observation of that.

e.g.

```
first(time_series["2006-06-17 12:00:00/2006-06-17 12:01"])
```

or, more generally, to get the 12:00 price every day, you can subset down to 1 minute of each day, then split by days and extract the first observation of each.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(time_series["T12:00:00/T12:01"],'days'), first))
```

Here's a thread where Jeff (the xts author) contemplates adding the functionality you want
http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Find-first-trade-of-day-in-xts-object-td3598441.html#a3599887